# ReactJs TypeError: handleChange is not a function

Tags: reactjs, console.log

I am trying to debug this error using console.log() to see where the error occurs. I am new to ReactJs, and this code comes from a tutorial. My app displays without error on the localhost:3000, until I enter a value, and then I get the "TypeError".

*console.log*(workworkwork) is logged in the console.

However, *console.log*(stuffystuff)is never executed.
Does this mean that the error occurs between my two console.logs()?

`Main.js`

```
  }
const Main = () => {
     const {formData, handleChange, sendTransaction} = 
     useContext; {TransactionContext}
     console.log("workworkwork")
 
     const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
       const { addressTo, amount } = formData
       e.preventDefault()

       if (!addressTo || !amount) return  

      sendTransaction()
      console.log("stuffystuff")
    }

    return (
          <div className= {style.wrapper}>
            <div className={style.content}>
             <div className={style.formHeader}>
              <div>Swap</div>
                <div>
                 <RiSettings3Fill />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={style.transferPropContainer}>
          <input
            type='text'
            className={style.transferPropInput}
            placeholder='0.0'
            pattern='^[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]*$'
            onChange={e => handleChange(e, 'amount')}
          />
         <div className={style.currencySelector}>
            <div className={style.currencySelectorContent}>
              <div className={style.currencySelectorIcon}>
                <Image src={ethLogo} alt='eth logo' height={20} width={20} />
              </div>
              <div className={style.currencySelectorTicker}>ETH</div>
              <AiOutlineDown className={style.currencySelectorArrow} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={style.transferPropContainer}>
          <input
            type='text'
            className={style.transferPropInput}
            placeholder='0x...'
            onChange={e => handleChange(e, 'addressTo')}
          />
          <div className={style.currencySelector}></div>
        </div>
        <div onClick={e => handleSubmit(e)} className={style.confirmButton}>
          Confirm
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
      )
  }

  export default Main
```

Comment: You have not added function definition for `handleChange`

Comment: Could you please show me how to do that, I am stuck?

Comment: Oh My apologies, it seems that the code has handleChange taken form context and that's where it is missing. can you please provide the complete code?